# The attached image is not retained with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The attached image is not retained if I validate the form with model . We use paperclip gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.4.0". I follow the following steps.

Steps:
The form has fields like
company_name(mandatory) 
location,
object_type,
object_size(mandatory) and 
attachment(mandatory).

1.Fill the fields company_name(mandatory),location,object_type and attach an image
2.Not to fill object_size(mandatory) which has model validation.
3.click on submit and the model validation is shown but the attached image disappear.

(Note: If the form is correctly filled at the first time the image is retained properly and stored in s3 database)

Can anybody help me plz.

Comment: Could you show us the server side code?

Comment: has_attached_file :attachment, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../config/s3.yml",
                                     :s3_protocol => 'http', :path => '/img-dev/:id.:extension',
                                     :url => ':s3_alias_url', :s3_host_alias => 'something',
                                     :bucket => 'something'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a file field in your form, the other three default paperclip object properties do not require form fields and are set through metadata tags on the image.

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :avatar, "Select Profile Picture*" %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
</p>
```

To validate use this in your model:

```
validates :avatar,   :attachment_presence => true,
                     :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => [ 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a file field a value, its a security risk

Example:

```
<form id="bad_form" action="/my_url">
  <input type="file" value="/Users/bob/my_very_secret_file.txt">
</form>
<script>
  $('#bad_form').submit();
</script>
```